# Geometrical probability distribution

Tags: probability

Suppose that 40% of the applicants for a certain statistical job possess advanced 
training in computer programming. Applicants are interviewed sequentially and are 
selected at random from the pool. Find the probability that the first applicant with 
advanced training in programming is found on the fourth interview.

So would this be:

$$
\begin{align}
P(Y = y) & = q^{(y-1)}\ p^1 \\
P(Y = 4) & = 0.6^3 \times 0.4
\end{align}
$$

I am not 100% sure about this.

Comment: Yes. First 3 must have no training, and then fourth must have training,

Comment: It is correct.  The reasoning is good too!